# How to structure BLoCs for screens with cross-dependent entities

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am currently trying to learn the BLoC pattern and still struggle with figuring out the best architecture for an app where entities in the model have cross-dependencies that also have implications on screens.

---

I am building a very simple CRUD Flutter app that allows the user to manage and tag a movie database. The database is implemented using the ***SQlite*** plugin and ***Drift***. So far, there are 4 main screens:

- MoviesListScreen
- MovieDetailsScreen
- TagsListScreen
- TagDetailsScreen

So obviously, the list screens list all movies / tags in the database, respectively, and allow you to add and delete entities. When you click on an entitiy on a list screen, you reach the details screen with all information on the respective movie / tag.

[From what I have read](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/182), it is recommended to have one bloc per feature or screen. Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-for-beginners-839e22adb9f5), I created two blocs, one for movies and one for tags. Here is the tags state:

```
enum TagsStatus { initial, success, error, loading, selected }

extension TagsStatusX on TagsStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == TagsStatus.initial;
  bool get isSuccess => this == TagsStatus.success;
  bool get isError => this == TagsStatus.error;
  bool get isLoading => this == TagsStatus.loading;
  bool get isSelected => this == TagsStatus.selected;
}

class TagsState extends Equatable {
  final TagsStatus status;
  final List<Tag> tags;
  final Tag selectedTag;
  final List<Movie> moviesWithSelectedTag;

  const TagsState(
      {this.status = TagsStatus.initial, List<Tag> tags, Tag selectedTag, List<Movie> moviesWithSelectedTag})
      : tags = tags ?? const [],
        selectedTag = selectedTag,
        moviesWithSelectedTag = moviesWithSelectedTag;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, tags, selectedTag];

  TagsState copyWith({TagsStatus status, List<Tag> tags, Tag selectedTag, List<Movie> moviesWithSelectedTag}) {
    return TagsState(
        status: status ?? this.status,
        tags: tags ?? this.tags,
        selectedTag: selectedTag ?? this.selectedTag,
        moviesWithSelectedTag: moviesWithSelectedTag ?? this.moviesWithSelectedTag);
  }
}
```

And the corresponding bloc:

```
class TagsBloc extends Bloc<TagEvent, TagsState> {
  final Repository repository;

  TagsBloc({this.repository}) : super(const TagsState()) {
    on<GetTags>(_mapGetTagsEventToState);
    on<SelectTag>(_mapSelectTagEventToState);
  }

  void _mapGetTagsEventToState(GetTags event, Emitter<TagsState> emit) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: TagsStatus.loading));
    try {
      final tags = await repository.getTags();
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: TagsStatus.success,
          tags: tags,
        ),
      );
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print(stacktrace);
      emit(state.copyWith(status: TagsStatus.error));
    }
  }

  void _mapSelectTagEventToState(event, Emitter<TagsState> emit) async {
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        status: TagsStatus.selected,
        selectedTag: event.selectedTag,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine to manage the loading of the list screens. *(Remark: I could create separate blocs for the details screens, because it feels a bit out of place to have the `selectedTag` bloc in the state that is used for the `TagsListScreen`, even though the selected tag will be displayed on a different screen. However, that would create additional boilerplate code, so I am unsure about it.)*

What I really struggle with is how to access all tags in the `MovieDetailsScreen` where I am using the `MoviesBloc`. I need them there as well in order to display chips with tags that the user can add to the selected movie simply by clicking on them.

I thought about the following possibilities:

1. Add all tags to the `MoviesBloc` - that would go against the point of having two separate blocs and I would have to make sure that both blocs stay in sync; moreover, a failure loading the tags would also cause a failure loading the movies, even in widgets that don't even use the tags
2. Subscribing to the `TagsBloc` in `MoviesBloc` - seems error-prone to me, also same as in point 1
3. Creating separate blocs for the list screens and details screens - lots of redundancy and additional boilerplate code
4. Nesting two `BlocBuilder` components in the `MovieDetailsScreen` - `BlocBuilder` [currently does not support more than one bloc](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/182), probably because this is an anti-pattern
5. Using one single bloc that holds movies as well as tags and use it in all 4 screens - discouraged by the creators of the BLoC package; also I would need two status properties to manage the loading from the database separately for movies and tags, which I feel should be in separate blocs

What would be the recommended way to handle this kind of business logic with blocs?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 4

As you're no dought aware, there are no correct and incorrect answers here, it's a matter of design. And if you ask me, I wouldn't consider *movies* and *tags* as two separate features, but that highly depends on the project domain and one's definition of a feature, so let's not go there.

Answering your question **I'd go with option 4**. Nesting `BlocBuilder`s is a quite common pattern in the bloc architecture, I've seen it many times.
Also, in the same thread you've referenced, the author [is recommending](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/182#issuecomment-478428917) that idea, so I don't think it's an anti-pattern.

p.s. option 3 is also fine, and maybe you can avoid the redundancy by creating a class that contains the shared logic between the two cubits, thus, you can still maintain them together, while having the perks of two separate blocs.

Comment: Well, I interpreted the author's comment in a way that that pattern was fine to apply from a technical point of view, but not necessarily that it was the best way to structure the app. I might be wrong though.

Comment: I didn't think about the possibility of several blocs sharing the same state, as I thought that there should be a 1:1 relation between blocs and state objects. If that is a legitimate pattern then that might be interesting, as I can manage the loading of movies in a single state and yet extract the `selectedMovie` state which is not needed in the `MoviesListScreen`.

Comment: @stefanS I wasn't talking about "several blocs sharing the same state". You're correct, states and blocs should have 1:1 relationship. What I meant is, a shared class between the two blocs where you define the **shared logic**. Because from what I've understood from you n.3 solution, the redundancy will be because of the logic shared between `TagsBloc` and `MoviesBloc`. you can think of that class as `SomeBusinessCaseHelper` and have methods like `doSharedLogic(Object args)` that can be called from the two cubits. Sorry, I couldn't provide a more specific example for your usecase.

Comment: @sharbel-ozkan Ok, that sounds reasonable. I could even use inheritance on the blocs to do that, but composition is probably cleaner. The states of the different blocs will probably need a common interface for the helper class to be able to emit new states depending on the previous state. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recommendation from the author of flutter_bloc available on the flutter_bloc documentation page.

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Some key-lines from the page:

> ...it may be tempting to make a bloc which listens to another bloc.
> You should **not** do this.

> ...no bloc should know about any other bloc.

> A bloc should only receive information through events and from injected repositories

So in short, something like your options 3 or 4. Perhaps with a touch of a `BlocListener` there to trigger events between the blocs.

There is no problem having multiple blocs per screen. Consider having a bloc controlling the state of a button based on some API calls or a Stream of data, while other parts of the screen are determined by another bloc.

It is not a bad thing to have an "outer" bloc determining if a part of a screen should be visible, but that inner part's state is handled by a separate bloc.

Answer (score 0):

> Subscribing to the TagsBloc in MoviesBloc - seems error-prone to me, also same as in point 1

This is the cleanest approach. I have been using it and it scales pretty well as number of blocs increases.

Comment: According to Robert's answer, dependencies between blocs are discouraged, because it creates a tight coupling between blocs that makes them hard to maintain.